# Pass typed text inside vscode snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

After reading the [snippets documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) I'm still searching a way to pass some text inside the snippet body by typing it after the snippet prefix.

Let's say I have a snippet with `log` prefix, I would like to transform the prefix in something like `log(*+)` to capture the text after.

If I type `loganObject`, the snipped should capture "anObject" and call my snippet to insert some text like `console.log ("the value of anObject is: ", anObject);`.

Is that possible?

I think that it is not possible because vscode should recognize that I'm still typing the prefix of the snippet and the text after the prefix should be captured and used inside the snippet body, but I hope they realized something like this.

Comment: It isn't possible like you want.  You would have to use a tabstop, like `$1` , and type your extra text there.  Or an extension like HyperSnips could probably do that.  You could make a keybinding that inserts a snippet though that reads the `log(...)` text and outputs what you want.

Comment: what is wrong with typing the `additional` text in a field (`$1`), by placing a `$0` you control where the cursor ends, could be inside the snippet.

Comment: @rioV8, Could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: it is all in the doc pages you have read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a keybinding that does what you want, but you have to select the text first <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> and that is the only text on the line.

Using `log.myTextHere` as the matched text, i.e., `log.` at the beginning just to be clear.

In your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+l",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "args": {
    // get the extra text into capture group 1
    "snippet": "console.log (\"${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^log\\.(.*)/the value of $1 is: \", $1/});"
  }
}
```

[image: console.log snippet demo]

---

Alternatively, and a little easier and more flexible, is to use an extension I wrote, [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview), to do this.  Use this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+y",                   // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    "preCommands": "cursorHomeSelect",    // does the selection for you
    "replace": [
      "$${",
              // log. = 4
      "let myVar = '${selectedText}'.substring(4);",
      "return `console.log (\"the value of ${myVar} is: \", ${myVar});`",
      "}$$"
    ],
    "restrictFind": "line"
  }
}
```

You could change `substring(4)` if you just want to use `log` and not `log.`.

[image: log snippet with Find and Transform extension]